# script to find the Position of Substring in Given String bin/bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, terminal

we have to write a shell program that will tell the position (index) of the substring in a given string.

- sample input:-

```
 Code Quotient - Get Better at Programming 
 at
```

- sample output :-
  28

i have written the code but it is giving -1 in every case..can pls someone help me finding the error.

```
#!/bin/bash
read a
read b
if [[ "$a" == "$b" ]]; then
    rest=${a#*$b}
    echo $(( ${#a} - ${#rest} - ${#b} +1 ))
else
    echo "-1"
fi
```

Comment: Change `==` to `=~`

Comment: Perhaps it will be easier this way: `rest=${a%%$b*}` `echo $((${#rest} + 1))`

Answer (score 1):

Your expression `[[ "$a" == "$b" ]]` checks to see if the two strings are the same. Since one is intended to be a substring of the other they will almost never match, so the `if` cannot succeed.